# Please suggest python code to clone repository from gitub having user and password

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse

username = rohan
Password = rohan!@#$
clonerepourl = https://rd667j@codecloud.web.att.com/scm/~vy381y/dcae_ms_status.git
MyDir = C://python//Rohan

I want to write python code to clone this repo to MyDir . Please help .
I tried below but didnt helped .
git clone https://rohan:rohan!@#$@https://rd667j@codecloud.web.att.com/scm/~vy381y/dcae_ms_status.git

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You need to show some code that you've written. We will help guide you but SO is not a code writing service. And I hope that is not really your password since you just posted it to a public forum.

Comment: This pass is not correct , just put is an similar example . I am trying to do like below but not working

from os import system

username = "rd667j" 
password = "Parlinb4!@#$" 

command_to_run = "git clone https://" + username + ":"+password+ "@github.com/"+username+"/"RepoURL

What exactly is missing and I have not added MyDir path here to save the cloned data , pelase suggest how to add .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Try to get de exactly command that you put in your console when you try to clone a repository:
For example:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Then you can use the `system` module in order to perform that command:

```
from os import system

username = "rohan" 
password = "rohan!@#$" 

command_to_run = "git clone https://" + username + ":"+password+ "@github.com/"+username+"/repository.git"


system(command_to_run)
```

Comment: Your advice to establish the needed git command line is spot on. But recommending `os.system()` is not. The recommended alternative since Python 2.4 (in 2003) has been the `subprocess` module.

Comment: good advice, but he didn't spicify much more details

Comment: Thanks Lain , I need to clone this to specific directory MyDir = C://python//Rohan

And my clone url from git hub is
RepoURL  = https://rd667j@codecloud.web.att.com/scm/~vy381y/dcae_ms_status.git

I tried to use above code shared by you but didnt get where to put my RepoURL and where to put MyDir path to save the cloned data .

Comment: could you please suggest , its urgent in my project .

Comment: can you clone your repository on your pc with this command?:
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git

If you can do that, pass me that exact command and I will make an example for you.